# Trying to identify the font for this number set

Tags: font-identification

I have the following number set that I have been having trouble finding the font for:

[image: number set]

There are no letter just the 0,2,3,4,5,6,and 7.

The digits were printed roughly 2014 if that helps any.

I tried a few web based upload the image and have the font identified, but they did not correctly identify the font.

I found the 3 is usually where the fonts failed to match up.  I did find two that were close in terms of shape, but the proportions were off and the 7 was wrong. They were [Cholla](http://www.identifont.com/list?1+104-.-2AA6-2ZI-8R0-DT-9C-6MA-4I6A-317M-235-2TBT-7VC-9M-83-F2T-20Z-6V-7C-1K7-9SR-1X0-KBZ-57VO-956-8A-3JI-57VF-1J8-57VJ-6Q-1LZ-3WO-7VQ-5NX-JIQ-95-DAU-4WTW-5NT-DP-6U-5PGQ-26R6-772-J4S-908-3AP-DAK-7B-5BV-96-2JQ-3S8-7M-87-8R3-99-1JU-1L1-3M5Z-80-57D-30C-B6F-571-6X-8RT-1JY-6ZQ-58C-7UF-76P-PAE-8J-9I-8Z-2BR-74-DG-1TM-8F-4PV-56V-8N-JPK-75-1KU-26RA-7P-7W-8W-8B-6X8-8E-6X4-7S-53K-1U6-1KK-79-1LA-1QY-7G-9Z+40.2777+N3S+4+54O+4+5YU+4+6RA+4+6R9+4+8M0+4+V+4+69U+4+2EE+4+5ZM+4+1FV+4+JXA+4+D7Q+4+HN1+4+HN2+4+HN3+4+6DK+4+6N4+4+61W+4+3G24+4+3G27+4+3G20+4+OZ+4+62V+4+2YK+4+3KC+4+248V+4+ANB+4+AN8+4+ANA+4) and [Fishmonger](http://www.identifont.com/list?1+104-.-2AA6-2ZI-8R0-DT-9C-6MA-4I6A-317M-235-2TBT-7VC-9M-83-F2T-20Z-6V-7C-1K7-9SR-1X0-KBZ-57VO-956-8A-3JI-57VF-1J8-57VJ-6Q-1LZ-3WO-7VQ-5NX-JIQ-95-DAU-4WTW-5NT-DP-6U-5PGQ-26R6-772-J4S-908-3AP-DAK-7B-5BV-96-2JQ-3S8-7M-87-8R3-99-1JU-1L1-3M5Z-80-57D-30C-B6F-571-6X-8RT-1JY-6ZQ-58C-7UF-76P-PAE-8J-9I-8Z-2BR-74-DG-1TM-8F-4PV-56V-8N-JPK-75-1KU-26RA-7P-7W-8W-8B-6X8-8E-6X4-7S-53K-1U6-1KK-79-1LA-1QY-7G-9Z+42.2777+N3S+4+54O+4+5YU+4+6RA+4+6R9+4+8M0+4+V+4+69U+4+2EE+4+5ZM+4+1FV+4+JXA+4+D7Q+4+HN1+4+HN2+4+HN3+4+6DK+4+6N4+4+61W+4+3G24+4+3G27+4+3G20+4+OZ+4+62V+4+2YK+4+3KC+4+248V+4+ANB+4+AN8+4+ANA+4)

I do not need the exact font, though that would be awesome, but something really close would do in a pinch.

Comment: The link is not working. Could you please cross check? Also do you want this font only or any similar recommendation would also work?

Comment: @Vikas updated Question with approximation answer, fixed one link and added another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pretty much *EA Sports* font. Not sure about official typeface name, but I could find it [here](https://www.dafont.com/ea-font.font?text=024753). But I'm **not sure** it's a free font as it is used in EA games. I wouldn't suggest to download it from this website, as it doesn't talk about its personal/commercial usage and license.

If you Google EA Cricket 2007, you'll see this:

[image]

0 and 7 are just like your image. The stroke in your image is manually added.

---

Here are the names of 2 alternative free fonts from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), that are a bit similar:

1. Bungee
2. Khand

You can just visit the website and search for these fonts.

Comment: I'll check and update about official typeface name and website.

Comment: That looks perfect for my needs.

Comment: I was able to download it from dafont.com.  on the right side of the page is states 100% free.

Comment: Yeah. It could be, but I'm still not sure.